# Bash: Expect different exit code with set -e

Tags: bash, exit-code

Consider a bash script that is executed with `set -e` enabled (exit on error).

One of the commands in the script returns an expected non-zero exit code. How to resume the script only when exactly this exit code is returned by the command? Note that exit code zero should also count as an error. A one-line solution would be best.

Example:

```
set -e

./mycommand  # only continue when exit code of mycommand is '3', otherwise terminate script

...
```

Comment: Note that using `set -e` is not universally considered a good idea -- its behavior is often deeply unintuitive, and [often incompatible](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/) not just between different shells but different releases of the same shell, making runtime behavior hard to predict. Reading [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) is strongly recommended.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the notes, unfortunately I have no control over the `set -e` in this context, I simply have to work around it

Comment: It *can* be turned off -- `set +e` does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would consist of two parts: Detecting error code 3, and turning zero to another

One possible solution would be like this

```
mycommand && false || [ $? -eq 3 ]
```

The first `&&` operator turns a zero exit code to 1 (with `false` - change to something else if 1 should be considered "good"), and then use a test to change the "good exit code" to 3.

A simpler, easier-to-maintain way would be to use a subshell:

```
( mycommand; [ $? -eq 3 ] )
```

This subshell will run `mycommand` normally and its exit code would be that of the latter sub-command. Just make sure you don't `shopt -s inherit_errexit` to ruin this :)

Answer (score 1):

Without using `set -e` which Charles Duffy pointed out in a comment is problematic:

```bash
# don't use set -e

./mycommand
if (( $? != 3 ))
then
    exit
fi

# more script contents follow
```

You can shorten that to:

```bash
# don't use set -e

./mycommand
(( $? != 3 )) && exit

# more script contents follow
```